# Do Twitter Card tags and OpenGraph meta tags conflict with each other? Do I need both?

Tags: facebook, open-graph-protocol

Pretty much the above, if I put Twitter card tags before my OpenGraph tags, will they conflict?

I ask because when it comes to each, I am pointing to different image sizes for the same content, as Facebook/Twitter have slightly different recommendations in this regard.

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Short answer: No they do not. Yes you should have both.

Order does not matter.

Twitter only detects the twitter card tags, and facebook only detects OG data.

Defining slightly different images, for twitter and facebook image guidelines is a good practice, though we just provide the same image to facebook and twitter. Twitter just crops it however it wants.

(The effort there is directly proportional to how much traffic facebook brings vs. twitter).

Answer (score 1):

I don't see how they would conflict, and as you say there are different recommended image sizes so use them both.

I have both Open Graph and Schema markup on my sites, it's just a few meta tags and a JSON object so they don't add much code to the page anyway.